# If the primary magento site folder is deleted and replaced with a backup will there be any issues?

Tags: magento2

I need to completely restore my magento 2 folder using a local backup I have. Will I face any issues if I completely remove the magento 2 folder on the server and reupload the backup folder to replace it?

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: If you want totally website like local then you need to replace the database also.
Otherwise settings will be from live one and files from local one.
Take back up before all you task do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue. But you need to change in app/etc/env.php from local to live database.

If you want whole the site from local to live than you need to migrate database also from local to live then it will work like you want.

Because if the setting of both is different in admin then it will not work as you want.

And do not forget to back up first to do all this things.

Thanks